# html form and negative top css values

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a small little search box form using CSS with a negative top value but when I do this you can no longer click in the text input box or click the button.
You can still tab to the form and functionality still works. I've tried positioning the form itself, putting the form in a div and positioning that, positioning a div inside the form and none seem to work.

Is there any way I can move this bit of HTML up about 50px without breaking it?

```
<form action="search.html" method="post">
<div class="searchBox" id="generalSearch">
<input type="submit" class="fbutton" style="font-size:12px;" value="" />
<input type="text" style="tsearch" name="searchString" maxlength="200" size="24" value="" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: please attach the css code for searchBox.

Comment: For debugging these issues, I set each element to have a different contrasting background-color so that it's totally obvious which element is where. Use nasty bright colours so that you don't forget to remove them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the CSS z-index a bit higher (like form#myForm {z-index:10;}). It's going *under* the element above.

Comment: Yup, I've run in to this issue myself a number of times.

Comment: Yeah, this is the issue. I realized that because of the layout of the site it's being overlapped by the element above it but it will be tricky to fix this because I have two divs that are siblings and the first must overlap the second. The search box is a child of the second div but must now overlap the first. I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do this. Here's a simple sketch of the site: http://kimag.es/share/29821158.gif

Answer (score 0):

Some other element on the page is interfering with your searchbox due to where it is positioned; not simply because you have a negative top value in CSS.

You can move the searchbox up 50px by reducing the top value by another 50px.

To remedy the interference, try lowering the other elements on the page by adding 50px to their top values.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem in IE or all browsers? If it's in IE only, try setting position:relative on the form (or other hasLayout trigger).

Also beware of z-index issues as SpliFF says.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the z-index. Truly powerful, but so misunderstood. Take a look and the W3 tutorials on z-index, that should help you with this issue.